# Error running the executable file (Tkinter python)

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, customtkinter

So I am using customtkinter for a small project and I made an executable file using pyinstaller. When I run the exe file I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module
  File "src\app\frontend\main_ui.py", line 250, in <module>
  File "src\app\frontend\main_ui.py", line 215, in __init__
  File "customtkinter\windows\ctk_tk.py", line 228, in wm_iconbitmap
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 2138, in wm_iconbitmap
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "data\images\valeo.ico" not defined
```

I tried a few solutions from stackoverflow, but it doesn't seem to work, apparently this is an issue in Linux but I am using Windows 11.

I would appreciate it if someone helps me in this matter.

Thank you.

Comment: The error looks like it expects to find a file which isn't there. We can't know what you packaged or what files exist on your system.

Comment: Take a note on the [Runtime Information](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html#run-time-information) when using PyInstaller.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the `.exe` file either doesn't contain the file `valeo.ico` or the file can't be accessed. Make sure that the `.exe` contains the icon file. If it does, and you still get the error, in your `.py` file, you need to access the icon file in a different way. Example code:

```
#Import the necessary modules
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import sys
import os

#Create a resource path function
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

#Create the screen
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

#Set icon
root.iconbitmap(resource_path("data\images\valeo.ico"))

root.mainloop()
```

When `Pyinstaller` is run using the `onefile` option, a temporary folder structure is created. The path to this structure in stored in `sys._MEIPASS`. So, we append the folder structure path to the path of our image file.

Comment: Note that `tkinter.PhotoImage()` does not support .ico file.  Also instance of `tkinter.PhotoImage` should be created after creating instance of `tkinter.Tk`.  Finally first argument of `.iconphoto()` is a boolean flag, not the instance of `PhotoImage`.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks for the info! I've edited my answer.